# SocketException: Weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

'm getting the following exception when try to query a page, from weblogic server 10.3. Kindly help me out to fix this issue.

```
java.net.SocketException: socket write error: Connection reset by peer.
at jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.writeBytesPinned(Native Method)
at jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.socketWrite(SocketNativeIO.java:46)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(SocketOutputStream.java)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedOutputStream.writeTo(ChunkedOutputStream.java:284)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeHeader(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:167)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ResponseHeaders.writeHeaders(ResponseHeaders.java:444)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.writeHeaders(ServletResponseImpl.java:1288)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.sendHeaders(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:424)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharsetChunkOutput.flush(CharsetChunkOutput.java:298)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput$2.checkForFlush(ChunkOutput.java:648)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharsetChunkOutput.write(CharsetChunkOutput.java:200)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:148)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:275)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it's related to some `Timeout` issues, check if you can increase it's value somewhere, I had rectified this error somewhere in my past, just forgot where exactly :( Or do check if the port is already in use, try to close the port down first.

Comment: pls, let me know where to increase the timeout value, and also the issue not consistent, it is happening randomly

Comment: Please do recheck, it must be on your `WebLogic User Interface`, or else do check if that port is already in use or not/

Answer (score 1):

It is related timeout issue. you can increment timeout by following way

Complete Message Timeout: Maximum value: 480

Maximum Message Size:
Minimum value: 4096
Maximum value: 2000000000
Secure value: 10000000

These are available at: server >>>>> AdminServer >>>> Protocols>>> General.

Also that would be better if your application compiled with the same java version that is used by the weblogic.

It could happen if you are not flushing the buffer.
Get read/write steams and control them with buffers.
you can even try increasing the jsp buffer size..
you could check if you have the same issue by switching the server to Sun JDK

Answer (score 1):

As before stated this error happens for many reasons. I will just give you some hints on troubleshoting.  First there are several types of logs with Weblogic architecture. This certainly can be a timeout issue, but can be many other reasons.  To debug it is important to understand the Weblogic architecture, configuration, and environment. First it important to determine which tier is throwing the root cause error.

This particular log appears to be Weblogic server log(Thrown before reaching the application). My next step would go to  your application.log to see if it generated any errors. That will rule out your application tier.  If no log exists create application log via application configuration or web console. Next if there is no corresponding error, then its time to troublshoot your webtier.

Webtier being Apache, Http server, or proxy.  Sometimes these can throw errors when certificates trusts etc not in alignment. Wallets and keystores.

If you are using nodemanager, that can also be a point of failure.

In my experience, this happens when the application tier croaks, database connection,network disconnect(user client tier) bad deployment, long running queries, or misconfigured certs or ports. Lastly, if this happens irregularly then in my experience it is normal too, but performance/load should be looked at.

Answer (score 0):

The client is closing the connection to the server, so Weblogic cannot write back the reply completely.

If this error is happening randomly, it can be due to an exception while processing the response in the client side.

If you have many clients, chances are some users get suddenly disconnected (e.g. client machine unplugged, program crash, etc.) while receiving the response from the server.

This error is very generic and can have multiple root causes.

BR